# Creating new fields inside a form with an incremental index in the name attribute, the variable seems to not be considered

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

This is a jsfiddle about the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/BHL3P/1/

```
var FiltersCount = 0;
var currentMinHeight = 20;
var filterDiv = "" +
    "<div style='border: 2px solid #003d4c; margin: 5px'>" +
    "<div style='width: 45%' class='input select'>" +
    "<label for='ReportFilter" + FiltersCount + "Field'>Select a Filter</label>" +
    "<select id='ReportFilter" + FiltersCount + "Field' style='width: 100%' name='data[Report][filter][" + FiltersCount + "][field]'>" +
    "<option value='product'>Filter" + FiltersCount + "</option>" +
    "</select>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<div style='width: 45%' class='input text'>" +
    "<label for='ReportFilter" + FiltersCount + "Value'>Type a Value</label>" +
    "<input type='text' id='ReportFilter" + FiltersCount + "Value' style='width: 100%' name='data[Report][filter][" + FiltersCount + "][value]'>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#moreFilters").append(filterDiv);

    $("#addFilter").click(function () {
        FiltersCount = FiltersCount + 1;
        $("#moreFilters").append(filterDiv);
    });
});
```

I'm creating a series of filters for a research form. Every field have a progressive number that differentiate the name from the others.

I'm clearly doing something wrong because even if the variable is changed, the created HTML keep using the initial value.

Comment: `$('.content')` doesn't match anything in your markup.

Comment: ******** u cache filterDiv go here : `s`http://jsfiddle.net/BHL3P/4/

Comment: You're right @oGeez. It's because it's copied from the real code. I'll remove the unnecessary codes from the question.

Comment: filterDiv  is declared only once.. it is a static string built up with  FiltersCount = 0 .... move in in the function and build it again each time before appending

Answer (score 0):

```
try this. i think because you save earlier on variable on top so it wont change value of filterscount inline on variable filterdiv. im not test it but i think it work.. sorry for my english :P




var FiltersCount = -1;
var currentMinHeight = 20;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addFilter").click(function () {
        FiltersCount = FiltersCount + 1;
       var filterDiv = "" +
    "<div style='border: 2px solid #003d4c; margin: 5px'>" +
    "<div style='width: 45%' class='input select'>" +
    "<label for='ReportFilter" + FiltersCount + "Field'>Select a Filter</label>" +
    "<select id='ReportFilter" + FiltersCount + "Field' style='width: 100%' name='data[Report][filter][" + FiltersCount + "][field]'>" +
    "<option value='product'>Filter" + FiltersCount + "</option>" +
    "</select>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<div style='width: 45%' class='input text'>" +
    "<label for='ReportFilter" + FiltersCount + "Value'>Type a Value</label>" +
    "<input type='text' id='ReportFilter" + FiltersCount + "Value' style='width: 100%' name='data[Report][filter][" + FiltersCount + "][value]'>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>";
        $("#moreFilters").append(filterDiv);
    });
});
```